# Array sorting using special XOR condition

Tags: c

I have a problem in understanding the condition of my program, I can hardly explain it in a sentence so I will explain the whole point of program.

So for my homework I got to make a program that will ask user to enter number N which will represent the number of elements in array, then user enters elements of that array (assuming that user will enter correct number of elements) program then needs compare every number from that array with a number X with XOR (^) Operator.

The task is to find a minimum value for that X in which will the resulting array have elements in ascending order. It sounds a bit complicated but this is how it should work:

- You enter a number N: For example lets use 4.
- Then you enter 1D array of 4 elements : Lets use 4 2 3 1
- Then program needs to use a number X (do while loop) to test every number from 
  this array with that number and if that number is >= to the previous one, it
  should continue to check the next and next until it reaches the number N
- If every element is sorted in ascending(equal counts as ascending) order it 
  should display that number.
- So for our example 4 2 3 1 when you use XOR operation with every one of them
  with the X=6 you get array that looks like this 2 4 5 7 which is in ascending 
  order.
- To explain: 4 in binary is 100 ; X in binary is 110 if you use XOR on 
  those you get 010  which is 2, and do as follows for the rest ( program does 
  everything)

So I made the program,everything works great returning good values for every example that we have for reference, my only problem is that I don't know when to stop looking for that number X, or how should I know that minimum X for that array of numbers doesn't exist. In that case my program runs forever and don't return any value,so basically an infinity loop.

I need to use code that is simple so nothing too complicated because this is a course "Introduction to programming" and they won't accept anything that was made using complex algorithms or something like that.

EDIt: The program should display -1 if there are no X.

Here is the code :

```
  #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

     int matrix[100];
     int n;

     int i;

     int index=1;
     int x=0;

     int start=0;
     int end=0;

    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

     for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
         scanf("%d",&matrix[i]);
     }

         index=1;
         x=0;
         do {
             start=matrix[index]^x;
                 if((matrix[index+1]^x) >= start)
                     index=index+1;
                else x++;

                 if(index==n){
                     printf("X=%d",x);
                     end=1;
                     break;
                 }

        } while(end!=1);

     return 0; }
```

Comment: So, given an array, you want to find a number X that is such that when all the elements from that array is XOR-ed with X, that array is sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Well I was wrong in the fact that I cant explain it in once sentence hahah. Yes thats the whole point I just need to find when to stop looking for the X if X does not exist for that array.

Comment: You don't reset index to zero when you increment x

Comment: Zero is not inside do while loop, so it wont be changed after the first run, my school uses c9 compiler which gives me and error that i'm "trying to access an uninitialized variable" something like that so I need put that there, even if i declared/initialized it in the beginning.

Comment: Can you use the fact that it's a limited, constant number of bits? Eg, 32?

Comment: I can't (and this is literally bolded text) use any kind of for loop that goes to a certain value(max number that int can store). But I think that I can use that facts.

Comment: Ahh, well then it would be easy to brute-force by going up the `INT_MAX`; but you only have to go up to that the max bits that is in any number. Eg, for your example, 4 is the max, `0b100`, so one would have to go up to `0b111 = 7`; any further and you are going to get equal results because all 0. Though, I have the intuition it's solvable in much less computation time, `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)` by considering the bits independently.